# Get contents of a particular row

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

I want to locate 'td' where text is 'xyz' so that I can find other attributes in the row. I only have 'xyz' with me and want to get other elements in that row.

```
.
.
.

<tr>
    <td>
        <a>xyz</a>
    </td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td>phone number</td>
</tr>

.
.
.
```

I can get 'xyz' easily by using

```
required = soup.find('a', text = 'xyz')
print(required[0].text)
```

but I'm not able to locate 'td' so that I can use `find_next_siblings()` to get other columns.

Expected output:

```
xyz
address
phone number
```

Comment: set id for html tag

Comment: @Internship TY use selenium with find_elements_by_css_selector:   https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1 combine pseudo classes of `:has` and `:contains` to retrieve the row and tds within.

This bit targets the right `a` tag if present by its text

```
a:contains("xyz")
```

You then retrieve the parent row (`tr`) having this `a` tag

```
tr:has(a:contains("xyz"))
```

And finally use a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) and `td` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/type_selectors) to get all the `td`s within that row. Using a list comprehension to return the list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>xyz</a>
    </td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td>phone number</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('tr:has(a:contains("xyz")) td')]
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<tr>
    <td>
        <a>xyz</a>
    </td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td>phone number</td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
required = soup.find('a', text = 'xyz')
print(required.text)
td = required.parent
siblingsArray = td.find_next_siblings()

for siblings in siblingsArray:
    print(siblings.text)
```

O/P:

```
xyz
address
phone number
```

Where `parent` is Get immediate parent tag and `find_next_siblings` return list of next siblings tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have modern BeautifulSoup, you can use CSS selector `:contains`. Then traverse back with `find_parent()` method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<tr>
    <td>Other1</td>
    <td>Other1</td>
    <td>Other1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a>xyz</a>
    </td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td>phone number</td>
</tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

for td in soup.select_one('a:contains(xyz)').find_parent('tr').select('td'):
    print(td.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
xyz
address
phone number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath. find_elements_by_xpath().

```
https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-xpath-locator/
```